# How to change the index of elements in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, indexing

I have an array:

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

I want to change the index of the elements in **b** based on this:

```
ind = [6, 4, 3, 9, 10, 8, 1, 5, 2, 7, 0]
```

The **correct** modified **b** would be:

```
modified_b = [11,7,9,3,2,8,1,10,6,4,5]
```

Here is what I tried:

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

ind = [6, 4, 3, 9, 10, 8, 1, 5, 2, 7, 0]

b_modified = []

for j in range(0,len(b)):
   b_modified.insert(ind[j],b[j])
print (b_modified)
```

The results is not correct:

```
[11, 1, 7, 9, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 5, 6]
```

Any idea how to do this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new list based on a zipped object of the index and the values:

```
>>> [t[1] for t in sorted(zip(ind,b))]
[11, 7, 9, 3, 2, 8, 1, 10, 6, 4, 5]
```

Or do a slice assignment to modify `b` in place:

```
>>> b[:]=[t[1] for t in sorted(zip(ind,b))]
>>> b
[11, 7, 9, 3, 2, 8, 1, 10, 6, 4, 5]
```

This will have reasonably performance on small to medium sized lists `O(n log n)`. If speed is a concern, you can replace the corresponding elements directly using `enumerate` to get `O(n)`:

```
mod_b=[None]*len(b)
for i,x in enumerate(ind):
    mod_b[x]=b[i]

>>> mod_b
[11, 7, 9, 3, 2, 8, 1, 10, 6, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks! I liked your last solution better!

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, sorting takes O(*n* log *n*) time, while O(*n*) time should be sufficient. For an O(*n*) solution, you can use a `for` loop with `zip`:

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
ind = [6, 4, 3, 9, 10, 8, 1, 5, 2, 7, 0]

res = [0] * len(b)
for val, idx in zip(b, ind):
    res[idx] = val

# [11, 7, 9, 3, 2, 8, 1, 10, 6, 4, 5]
```

`list.insert` isn't appropriate here, as you can't access indices which don't already exist in a list. Since you know the size of your result beforehand, you can just instantiate a list with this size.

You can also use 3rd party [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), which supports vectorised indexing:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
ind = np.array([6, 4, 3, 9, 10, 8, 1, 5, 2, 7, 0])

res = np.empty(b.shape)
res[ind] = b

# array([11.,  7.,  9.,  3.,  2.,  8.,  1., 10.,  6.,  4.,  5.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new empty array and assign the indexes:

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
ind = [6, 4, 3, 9, 10, 8, 1, 5, 2, 7, 0]

b_modified = [0] * len(b)

for i in range(len(ind)):
    b_modified[ind[i]] = b[i]

print(b_modified)

>>> [11,7,9,3,2,8,1,10,6,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the builtin `sort` function of the `list` type:

```
sorted(b, key=lambda x: ind[x-1])
```

will return a new list sorted as desired.

If you want to do the sorting in-place:

```
b.sort(key=lambda x: ind[x-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using NumPy, as jpp suggested but, to end with a list use the tolist() method:

`b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
ind = [6, 4, 3, 9, 10, 8, 1, 5, 2, 7, 0]
c=np.array(b)[ind].tolist()`